# Auto layout issue vertically aligned UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Why this piece of code doesn't work as a container of a vertically aligned UILabels? What's wrong?

```
self.daysContainer = [[UIView alloc]init];
[self.daysContainer setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
UILabel *dayview1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
UILabel *dayview2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[dayview1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[dayview2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.daysContainer addSubview:dayview1];
[self.daysContainer addSubview:dayview2];
dayview1.text = @"DayView 1";
dayview2.text = @"DayView 2";
dayview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NSDictionary *elementsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(dayview1, dayview2);
[self.daysContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[dayview1]-[dayview2]-|"                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil                                                                 views:elementsDict]];
[self.daysContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[dayview1]-|"                                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil                                                                    views:elementsDict]];
[self.daysContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[dayview2]-|"                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil                                                                     views:elementsDict]];
```

Comment: Where are you setting the constraints on daysContainer itself?

Comment: @DanielToranzoPerez You are dynamically creating container view right? After creation whether you added this to main view?

Comment: Container view is created in the storyboard. The UILabels are created dynamically. I am in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is that the only source of vertical constraints

```
[self.daysContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[dayview1]-[dayview2]-|"                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil                                                                 views:elementsDict]];
```

does not contain information in the visual format string about how tall either of the two views should be. If they should be equal, using the visual format `@"V:|-[dayview1(dayview2)]-[dayview2]-|"` should handle it. You could also specify to add any space to the end, `@"V:|-[dayview1]-[dayview2]-(>=20)-|"`

Comment: in self.view it works and the problem is when i try to add the constraint to a specified container. The (>=20) is not needed because: H:|-[dayview1]-|

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:**
    self.daysContainer = [[UIView alloc]init];
was creating a new instance, so the constraints are not being added in the storyboard.

Thanks and great support!